# (FLUTTER) Grid View Sometimes loads and sometime doens't in release apk

Tags: android, flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I have completed this app, and it works fine when i run this app on my device.
But after i build and install the release apk, the Grid View sometime renders the list and sometimes doenst. for i.e. when 2 out of 5 times when i open the app from my phone home screen, the grid view doesnt display the list.

I would like to understand and fix this weird issue in flutter!

[image: empty]
[image: Grid list]

MAIN PAGE

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    indicatorColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
      primary: Colors.pinkAccent,
    ),
    canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 254, 229, 1),
    fontFamily: 'Raleway',
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Roboto',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            fontSize: 23) //Fontweightis700 for bold
        ),
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 17,
        fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      bodyText1: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12,
        fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
      )
    ),
  ),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: "Meals App",
  initialRoute: '/', //default value is '/'
  routes: {
    '/' : (_) => const TabsPage(),
    FoodListPage.routeName : (_) => FoodListPage(),
    MealDetailPage.routeName : (_) => MealDetailPage(),
    FiltersPage.routeName : (_) => FiltersPage(),
  },
  onGenerateRoute: (settings){
    print(settings.name);
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => CategoryPage());
  },
  onUnknownRoute: (setting){
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => CategoryPage());
  },
);
```

}

TABS PAGE

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
  initialIndex: 0,
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("MealsApp"),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      child: const TabBar(
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        labelColor: Colors.white,
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.category,
            ),
            text: 'Categories',
          ),
          Tab(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.star,
            ),
            text: 'Favorites',
          ),
        ],
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
        indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      children: [
        CategoryPage(),
        FavoritesPage()
      ],
    ),
    drawer: MainDrawer(),

  ),
);
```

}

CATEGROY PAGE

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GridView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
      childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
    ),
    children: [
      ...DUMMY_CATEGORIES
          .map((item) => CategroyItem(item.id, item.title, item.color))
          .toList()
    ],
  );
```

}

CATEGORY ITEM PAGE

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
      FoodListPage.routeName,
      arguments: {'id' : id, 'title' : title}
    );
  },
  splashColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Text(title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [color.withOpacity(0.5), color],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
  ),
);
```

}

DUMMY CATEGROY LIST

```
const DUMMY_CATEGORIES =  [
```

Category(
id: 'c1',
title: 'Italian',
color: Colors.purple,
),
Category(
id: 'c2',
title: 'Quick & Easy',
color: Colors.red,
),
Category(
id: 'c3',
title: 'Hamburgers',
color: Colors.orange,
),
Category(
id: 'c4',
title: 'German',
color: Colors.amber,
),
Category(
id: 'c5',
title: 'Light & Lovely',
color: Colors.blue,
),
Category(
id: 'c6',
title: 'Exotic',
color: Colors.green,
),
Category(
id: 'c7',
title: 'Breakfast',
color: Colors.lightBlue,
),
Category(
id: 'c8',
title: 'Asian',
color: Colors.lightGreen,
),
Category(
id: 'c9',
title: 'French',
color: Colors.pink,
),
Category(
id: 'c10',
title: 'Summer',
color: Colors.teal,
),
];

Comment: What is dummy categories here? Is it being fetched from an api?

Comment: No! i have seperate class file which holds the list of this data!

Comment: Is this dummy categories being used anywhere else?

Comment: @KaushikChandru no sir, only this page is accessing that categories List.

Comment: That's strange can you clear cache and try again?

Comment: yes sir, it did work fine for the first 3 times but the 4th, time list didnt load. Happens same  in my friends device. Could it happen cause of bottom tab navigation or side drawer?

Comment: include full codes here.

Comment: OK I HAVE INCLUDED all the required files in the post? Is there anything else i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code multiple times. Not sure how you have defined the variables though. But this is definitely working on any number of opens from the home page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: TabsPage());
  }
}

class TabsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabsPage> createState() => _TabsPageState();
}

class _TabsPageState extends State<TabsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("MealsApp"),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          child: const TabBar(
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.category,
                ),
                text: 'Categories',
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.star,
                ),
                text: 'Favorites',
              ),
            ],
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [CategoryPage(), CategoryPage()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CategoryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Category> DUMMY_CATEGORIES = [
    Category(
      id: 'c1',
      title: 'Italian',
      color: Colors.purple,
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c2',
      title: 'Quick & Easy',
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c3',
      title: 'Hamburgers',
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c4',
      title: 'German',
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c5',
      title: 'Light & Lovely',
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c6',
      title: 'Exotic',
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c7',
      title: 'Breakfast',
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c8',
      title: 'Asian',
      color: Colors.lightGreen,
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c9',
      title: 'French',
      color: Colors.pink,
    ),
    Category(
      id: 'c10',
      title: 'Summer',
      color: Colors.teal,
    ),
  ];
  CategoryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      ),
      children: [
        ...DUMMY_CATEGORIES
            .map((item) => CategoryItem(item.id, item.title, item.color))
            .toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  String id;
  String title;
  Color color;
  CategoryItem(
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.color, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [color.withOpacity(0.5), color],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Category {
  String id;
  String title;
  Color color;
  Category({required this.id, required this.title, required this.color});
}
```

Comment: It was happening because I used Tabs widget in bottomNavigationBar:  property in scaffold. I should instead use BottomNavgiationTab.